# how to initialize the flickity in vue2.js?

Tags: vuejs2, flickity

I am using flickity, but it is not initialized, I have to do it manually in the google chrome console.

**index.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js" defer></script>
```

page.vue

```
<div class="carousel" data-flickity='{ "autoPlay": true }'>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
</div>
```

already try manually in the index.html in this way

```
$('.carousel').flickity();
```

Comment: Are you using the webpack version of vue?

Comment: @samayo yes, It is a project generated with vue-cli

Comment: then have you tried doing like this https://github.com/misterGF/CoPilot/blob/08212c164a314ff38a274d699745f4fc9c0070bb/src/components/views/Tables.vue#L199 and then use it

Comment: yes but I get the following error `[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_jquery___default(...)(...).flickity is not a function"

found in

---> <Show> at src/components/profile/show.vue
       <Profile> at src/components/layouts/profile.vue
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>` @semayo

Comment: then that is a jquery error, maybe it's a library or something